# Compile TypeScript only during Rebuild and Publish

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, csproj

I currently have

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
  <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>       
</PropertyGroup>
```

in .csproj so TypeScript is not compiled when building in Debug mode. Is it possible to compile TypeScript during Publish and Rebuild but not during Build in Visual Studio regardless of `Configuration` (Debug/Release) and `Platform`?

The reason I am asking is because compiling TypeScript is extremely slow while building the project. CompileOnSave is pretty fast though and good enough for development most of the time. But sometimes it's required to compile everything TypeScript and that would be nice during rebuilding.

Comment: Is this a classic asp.net project or asp.net core?

Comment: @MartinUllrich asp.net core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Compile TypeScript only during Rebuild and Publish

AFAIK, there is no directly way that we could compile TypeScript only during Rebuild and Publish. As a workaround, we could rebuild/publish the project via MSBuild command line with parameter `/p:TypeScriptCompileBlocked=False`:

```
msbuild.exe "YourSolution.sln" /t:rebuild /p:TypeScriptCompileBlocked=False
```

With this way, we can build the project via MSBuild command line when required to compile everything TypeScript.

Hope this helps.